# Python bot Telegram Как сделать анимационный текст в одной строчке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите как сделать анимационный текст в боте телеграм.
Суть такая:
Пользователь делает запрос на получение информации, бот отправляет сообщение в одной строке вида:
'Поиск информации...' 'Поиск блаблабла...' 'Информация найдена...'

И следующим сообщением вылетает нужная информация.
К примеру фотография

Answer (score 0):

```
load = 'Loading, please wait {}%'
wait = bot.send_message(chat_id, load.format(0))
time.sleep(1)
bot.edit_message_text(load.format(50), chat_id, wait.message_id)
time.sleep(1)
bot.edit_message_text(load.format(100), chat_id, wait.message_id)
```

Надеюсь идею вы поняли

Comment: Правда в таком случае бот будет виснуть при каждом изменении

Comment: Тогда нужно открывать новый поток для каждого сообщения или сделать бот асинхронным